# MYSQL: Count the number of row in one table based on the join of two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables, Entries, Institution and Doctors. Here is a minimal example fo the table data:

ENTRIES

```
| keyid  | doctorid | 
---------------------
|  1     |    23    |
|  2     |    13    | 
|  3     |    23    | 
|  4     |    13    | 
|  5     |    23    |
|  6     |    42    | 
|  7     |    5     |
```

INSTITUTION

```
| name   |
----------
|  One   |
|  Two   |
|  Three |
|  Four  |
|  Five  |
|  Six   |
```

DOCTORS

```
| uid      |   inst   | 
-----------------------
|  23      |    Three |
|  13      |    Six   | 
|  3       |    Four  | 
|  42      |    Six   | 
|  5       |    One   |
```

What I need to know is the number of entries that I have for each institution. However the institutions are linked to the entries through the DOCTORS table. So the result in this case should give me this:

RESULTS

```
| name     | count |
--------------------
| One      |  1    |
| Two      |  0    |
| Three    |  3    |
| Four     |  0    |
| Five     |  0    |
| Six      |  3    |
```

I have no idea how to even start writing this query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start by joining the 3 tables.

Comment: I've allready done that previously (SELECT DISTINCT i.name, i.uid, r.keyid
FROM INSTITUTION AS i, ENTRIES AS r, DOCTORS as d
WHERE (i.name = d.inst) AND (d.uid = r.doctorid);). However I don't know how to format this in order to get what I need.

Comment: Don't use implicit joins use explicit joins and do read up on mysql aggregate functions.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Still struggling? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. I can't even begin to write a query that seems to do what I want. My only attempt was met with a syntax error that I don't know how to correct and I'm on the clock. I really don't know how to even begin to write the query because I don't how to make the COUNT count what I want. So, I'm giving up. I'm just doinng the query I provided and then do an external for cycle to count the number fo resultls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with an aggregated query that JOINs all three tables, like :

```
SELECT
    i.name,
    COALESCE(COUNT(e.keyid), 0) cnt
FROM
    institution i
    LEFT JOIN doctors d ON d.inst = i.name
    LEFT JOIN entries e ON e.doctorid = d.uid
GROUP BY i.name
```

Using your sample data, this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7aYMzWXkD9hjK8fYjUmkvP/0)** returns :

```
| name  | cnt |
| ----- | --- |
| One   | 1   |
| Two   | 0   |
| Three | 3   |
| Four  | 0   |
| Five  | 0   |
| Six   | 3   |
```

PS : depending on your data, you might want to use `COUNT(DISTINCT e.keyid)`.

Comment: Im away from my computer right now. But I had to look up COALESCE. If I understood it correctly, you only used it to return 0 for those institutions that did not have any entries. Is this correct?

Comment: @aarelovitch : yes this is correct. Without COALESCE we would have NULL values.

Comment: So I finally got to try you query. It did not work. And frankly the results I've got made no sense. A single row was returned (and It should have returned about 5). Furthermore the value of cnt was higher than the number of rows in the entres table

Comment: @aarelovich : I did a few fixes in the query and tested it, AFAIK it works fine now !

Comment: THANK YOU!!! However one small correction. I made the sample data. The real data set was too complicated to reproduced. However the query still gave me more results than there were  rows in the entry table. That is when I relized I needed a DISTINCT in the COUNT in order to count ONLY different entries. This did the trick!!